# Cordova + Angular 4 + Typescript boilerplate template

Tags: angular, cordova, progressive-web-apps, boilerplate

I'm working on a Web Progressive App using Angular 4.
This app needs to be wrapped up in an Apache Cordova as a Hybrid app built for Android and iOS platforms.

I'm looking for a working boilerplate template for Cordova + Angular 4.
Cordova is using `www` folder for web app and Angular 4 is using `src` folder for web app. How to merge this two together to work? 
Angular 'ng serve' should also work?

Comment: If you used angular cli to general the app (highly recommended) you can change the apps->root in your .angular-cli.json from 'src' to 'www'

Comment: Thanks for that. I found apps: [ "root" ] in .angular-cli.json file and changed it from 'src' to 'www' because Cordova uses 'www' app folder.

Comment: Now when both Cordova and Angular are using the same 'www' folder, I can start ng server using 'ng serve' and view my app in 'localhost:4200'. But when I build Cordova app it starts 'index.html' from 'www' but it doesn't recognize <app-root></app-root> (angular directives) to load angular. Is that possible in Cordova?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Cordova to guide you on that one, sorry

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I finally manage to solve my problem.

- We need to merge Cordova **"www"** folder and angular **"src"** folder in one **"src"** folder where angular app should be.
- **package.json** needs to be merged as well to fit for both Cordova and Angular.
- Then, (thanks to Gangadhar Jannu for the tip), we need to change in ".angular-cli.json" property **"outDir"** to **"www"** because Cordova uses that folder for building their app.
- Then we need to compile Angular app using CLI: **"ng build --prod"**.
- Finally build cordova app: **cordova build android|browser|ios|..**

Here is a working boilerplate:

https://github.com/NavCore/ngCordova

Comment: Have been struggling with the same. I asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49594706/using-angular-with-cordova  I was using `ng build` but using `ng build --prod` solved the issue

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change the output directory of ng cli you can configure `outDir` property in the **.angular-cli.json** as shown below:

```
  "outDir": "../public",
```

Then you can use `ng build` command to build the angular application in the `outDir` that you've specified previously

Comment: That is an output directory, and I needed project directory. It's in the same .angular-cli.json file -> apps: [ "root" ] property !!

Comment: Thanks Gangadhar Jannu for the answer. Yes, that is a partial answer for my problem. We need to compile angular using "outDir" as "www" folder because Cordova uses that folder for building app.