# Using Angular with Cordova

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to add angular 5 to cordova and create a project. And no I DO NOT want to use ionic.

I am following the following tutorial on the web
https://medium.com/@nacojohn/convert-your-angular-project-to-mobile-app-using-cordova-f0384a7711a6

when I run `ng serve` my app launches in the browser and when I do `cordova build android`  my app is built successfully.

But as soon as I launch the app in an emulator I get the following error and a white screen

`compiler.js:16014 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Do let me know where is the issue?

Thanks

Note: I am simple using the started project generated by angular cli which is why I am not adding any code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can, try running it on a real device. Emulators have issues with outdated browsers which aren't compatible with Angular 5 browser support - https://angular.io/guide/browser-support. I tried the above and it was launching successfully on my device.

To sort this out, I enabled the ES6 support on older browsers by:

1. Edit the polyfills.ts in your /src folder. Uncomment the following lines

`import 'core-js/es6/symbol';`

`import 'core-js/es6/object';`

`import 'core-js/es6/function';`

`import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';`

`import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';`

`import 'core-js/es6/number';`

`import 'core-js/es6/math';`

`import 'core-js/es6/string';`

`import 'core-js/es6/date';`

`import 'core-js/es6/array';`

`import 'core-js/es6/regexp';`

`import 'core-js/es6/map';`

`import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';`

`import 'core-js/es6/set';`

2. Run the `ng build` command and finally `cordova build android`

The above steps sorted it for me.

Regards

Comment: instead of doing `ng build` by doing `ng build --prod` solves this issue for me.