# Responsive Angular App with cordova/ionic

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

i need a architect advance.
I have small responsive angular application with authorization and authentication. I want to also have my website like a application in android and ios opearting systems. After my research i found cordova and ionic technology which in my opinion looks good for the task but i have a lot of question in my mind.
Should i create new ionic project and hand copy parts of code which i want to use in mobile app or should i add ionic to my project like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45763626/cordova-angular-4-typescript-boilerplate-template)? How is it done in a commercial projects? Should i have one repository for those project (i think 95% of the code will be same, maybe 100% – i'm not sure how works authorization and authentication on mobile)? How is the good way to do this? Maybe i don't need ionic i should only use cordova.

I really thanks in advance for any helps and tips. I really don't want to spend time on trying every approach.

Comment: ionic is better, try ionic

Comment: With Cordova is enough for what you want to do. Search How add Cordova in an existing Angular project

Answer (score 0):

Ionic is built on top of cordova. Ionic is more powerful in my opinion because you have custom components and things like that.

Ionic also uses Angular so you are already on the other side. You don't have to have to code bases. Ionic is a multi-platform framework. You can use it for web app, ios, and android. But even if you decide to have 2 different codes I'm pretty sure there a way to share components, services for both apps (your responsive one and the ios/android one)

I love Ionic. They have their own IDE, there are Ionic plugins for VS Code and they even have their own drag and drop builder online

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer helped me.